# Automorphic number in python

Tags: python

Many interview panels have asked this question to me in the interview to find the if a given number is an automorphic number or not.

[image]

I have added the above code which I got to my knowledge. Please add if another simple logic to solve this problem.

Comment: Please how code as text, not images

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question and is instead soliciting review or enhancement. It also provides no textual [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
num = int(input('enter a number'))
if str(num) == str(num**2)[-len(str(num)):] :
    print (num , 'is Automorphic ')
else :
    print (num , 'is not Automorphic ')
```

Comment: Guessing you meant `-len(str(num))`.

Comment: nope `[len(str(num)):]` works fine

Comment: I recommend revisiting the definition of automorphic, or test your code with the first 5 automorphic numbers because 3 out of 5 will fail.

Comment: I tried many automorphic numbers it workes fine without the - . It could be a coincidence but as u said `[-len(str(num)):]` is more logic

Comment: Your original code works iff the number of digits in N squared is 2x the number of digits in N.

Comment: indeed automorphic numbers are 2x the number of digits in N this why the orignal code works

Comment: They're not. Some are, but some are not. Examples: 0, 1, 25, and more.

Comment: thank you for helping.